# How do I intercept a 404 error in PHP properly?

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-code-404, errordocument

Essentially, what I am doing is intercepting a 404 using ErrorDocument in .htaccess, and pointing it at getFile.php.  getFile then grabs the file name out of the url and searches for it in the mysql database, getting the data and applying appropriate headers.

In my dev environment (up-to-date LAMP server running under ubuntu) everything seems to work fine, but the site is being hosted on GoDaddy, and there seems to be some issue with the headers returned.  I think GoDaddy returns a 404, then sends the data anyway.

The result is when I right click on a link that is to be handled in this manner, I can 'Save As', and everything works fine.  If the file is an image, it opens no problem.  But if I just click the link and it is a file that is to be downloaded rather than viewed in a browser, I get 'File Not Found' errors, across all browsers.  Firebug Console claims it is a 404 error, regardless of whether the file successfully transfers.  My code is the following:

```
$folder = explode( "/" , $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
$pageName = $folder[sizeof($folder)-1];

$sql = "SELECT data, mimeType, OCTET_LENGTH(data) AS size FROM tblFiles WHERE fileName = '".$pageName."' AND active=1;";

$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die();

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
header("Content-Type: ".$data['mimeType']);
header("Content-Length: ".$data['size']);

echo $data['data'];
```

And the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /FILES/dbFiles/getFile.php
```

Now this is the full .htaccess file present at /FILES/dbFiles.  I don't know if GoDaddy is expecting more stuff in there, but it seems to work just as written on my own server.

I've tried numerous combinations of header info with no positive effect.

My code apparently works, but I can't seem to prevent that 404 from happening.

Thanks!
-Jer

Comment: sending a 200 OK header when a user accesses a missing page is normally bad practice.

Comment: I've tried it with and without, and there seems to be no effect.  In the full code, it only sends the 200 when the data is found in the database.  Also, this .htaccess file applies only to this directory, as to handle the database file request.  It does not affect the rest of the site.

Comment: Have you tried `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.txt"');`?

Comment: Yes I have.  Same thing.  It seems as though GoDaddy sends the 404 prior to any header info I attempt to send, so I'm kind-of leaning toward an issue with the .htaccess file.

Comment: maybe email GoDaddy and ask them how they handle 404s

Comment: www.example.com/;#DROP TABLE user;DROP TABLE content...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your `/FILES/dbFiles/.htaccess` file (without the ErrorDocument part):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ getFile.php?file=$0 [QSA,L]
```

This will direct all non-existing URLs to your `getFile.php` script without generating a 404.  Make sure you *do output* a 404 if the script does not find the content in your database.

Inside your PHP file, use:

```
if(@$_GET['file']) {

    //Your code here.  Use $_GET['file'] instead of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]

} else {
    //Weird.  This file was directly accessed.
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, nice solution.  My situation was this: I was streaming javascript content from another directory when a requested .js file didn't exist, and while the actual content of the javascript was returning just fine the status was 404.

For my purposes this is what helped, hopefully it helps others too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) route/index.php [L,QSA]
```